# Why POST in red language change the first character of parameters to upper-case automaticlly?

Tags: post, red

For the following simple code,

```
Red []

#include %tools.red

url: to url! rejoin ["http://somesite.com:7466/japi"]

response: write url [
        post [
        Content-Type: "application/json"
        req: "requestinfo"  
        list: "This is a pie."
    ]
    {}    
]

print response
```

The result is something like:

> {"Status":"fail","Value":"unknown request: \u0026{POST /japi HTTP/1.1
>   1 1 map[Accept:[*/*] Content-Type:[application/json] Req:[requestinfo]
>   List:[This is a pie.] Content-Length:[0]] {} \u003cnil\u003e 0 []
>   false somesite.com:7466 map[] map[] \u003cnil\u003e map[]
>   176.116.100.233:31144 /japi \u003cnil\u003e \u003cnil\u003e \u003cnil\u003e 0xc0002a2640}"}

My question is, why the parameters (such as req, list) are automatically capitalized?

Comment: Is this happening for all requests that return a JSON? And not when you make request using cURL or Postman?

Comment: not only JSON response, others are same

Comment: I've changed the URL to `https://ident.me/.json` that returns a JSON, and no capitalized occurs: `{"address": "xx.xx.xx.xx"}`. Could it be related to your `tools.red` file? What does it do?

Comment: return value is not capitalized, I mean the parameters in the request. And there is almost no code in tools.red .

Comment: The server response is generated according to the request.

Comment: Header field names are supposed to be case-insensitive... its the japi server side which should handle it. The reason why Red is modifying it may be because of estetic reasons but also because some servers may have problems when there is not the notation like Content-Length.

Comment: It might change when the full IO work completed, on next major release `v0.7.0`.

Comment: Ok, I am looking forward it(the new release), since the server side is written by myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTTP/1.1 RFC says in [section 4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.2):

> Each header field consists of a name followed by a colon (":") and the field value. Field names are case-insensitive.

Therefore, capitalization of first character of header names has no side-effect on a compliant HTTP server.

Though, from the "parameters" term you are using, and the `req: "requestinfo"` part in your source code, I wonder if you are not trying to pass those information as POST data rather, by mistakenly putting them in the headers list. If that is the case, then the right way to pass them is:

```
Red []

#include %tools.red

url: http://somesite.com:7466/japi

response: write url [
    POST [Content-Type: "application/json"]
    "req=requestinfo&list=This%20is%20a%20pie."  
]

print response
```

Comment: This answer is perfect. Except change "Content-Type" to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". Thanks a lot.